# How can I merge an image with text

Tags: media

I want to create a greeting card and send to the users email. How can I merge text on an image?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar: [Drupal 7 view Image Text overlay on Hover](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/149191/1908)

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Image Cache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions):

> Effects provided
>
> - Watermarking - a much requested addition that enables
>     you to place any image anywhere over a source picture, with alpha
>     transparency
> - Overlays - Add photo-corners etc to the image
> - Text overlay - add a short copyright notice to your image, using available
>     system fonts
> - Color-shifting - Colorize images. Also invert.
> - Brighten/Darken Alpha blending - turn an image into a transparent
>     mask, and back into a flat image against another color
> - Canvas manipulation - add padding, either onto color or transparent
>     backgrounds
>     *Background - Place your image onto another source
>     background
> - File Format switcher - If you need tranparency in JPGs :
>     make them PNG. If your PNG thumbnails are 30K each, save them as JPGs.
>     (This is distributed as part of the color-actions submodule)
> - Rounded corners (transparent). With input from canaryMason, we can even set
>     different radius for different corners, and round just one corner etc.
> - Aspect Switcher - lets you perform different actions or use different
>     dimensions based on whether the image is 'landscape' or 'portrait'
> - Custom Actions - Execute your own PHP/GD code in the middle of an
>     imagecache generation process. Requires some familiarity with imageAPI
>     internals.
> - Posterize new as of 7.x-1.4- Reduce the image to a limited
>     number of color levels per channel. This effect can be used to reduce
>     file size on png images.

*How* this module adds text over an image (which is your question) I leave to you to figure out by browsing and deconstructing the module sourcecode.