# How to view blocks with Text Overlay on hover?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, modal-dialogs

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site and I want to achieve similar thing (view blocks with Text Overlay on hover) shown here. http://ibakatv.com/ under the following blocks (sub sections):
Basically I would like to show text upon mouse hover just like what is shown on the above website.

- MOVIE TRAILERS
- TRENDING MOVIES ..
- LATEST MOVIES etc etc

Also, can someone help how to achieve those view blocks with the navigation as listed above? Do you know this was done? I looked at [BX Slider](http://www.drupal.org/project/bxslider), but I'm unable to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be a variation of [Create a simple Text over Image Overlay on Hover with Drupal 7 and Views](http://www.faennj.de/en/blog/create-a-simple-text-over-image-overlay-on-hover-with-drupal-7-and-views/may-2015). If you also install/enable the [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) module, the node title shown over the image can be a hyperlink to the node also.

Especially this part in it seems to be what you're looking for (be it with some minor variations):

> Create a view 'Overlay'. Create a page which shows content of type 'overlay-image'. It shows an unformatted list of fields. Save and edit. On the edit page, add the fields 'Content: Image' and 'Content: Link' to the fields and exclude them from display.  For the last field add 'Global: custom text'. In the text field, write: `<ul class="img-list"><li>[field_image]<span class="text-content"><span>[field_link]</span></span></li></ul>`

Curious to hear if this somehow will help ...